$n\star n - 2\cdot n = (n-1)\star [(n\star n - n - n^2)/n],\,$ where $\star$ is decimal digits concatenation
$n\star n - 2\cdot n = (n-1)\star [(n\star n - n - n^2)/n],\,$ where $\star$ is  decimal digits concatenation
Example: ($n = 23$)
$$23\star 23 - 2\cdot 23 =2323-2\cdot 23= 2277= 22\star 77= (23-1) \star \frac{2323 - 23 - 23^2}{ 23} $$

This is hard to read.  If $nn$ is $n$ concatenated with $n$, what is $n^2$?  Or are these strings of digits that can be interpreted as integers?  What is "$a$"?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

A hint: denote by $\ell$ the number of digits of $n$. Can you rewrite $n\star n$ as a quantity that depends on $n$ and $\ell$?

They helped me edit the question. Now it looks readable. Thank you Kolakoski54

To be up to the standard of MSE, we still need you to write what you tried! It's a good start to try with an example (as you did). Note that $23\star 23=2300+23$. So, in general, can you guess how to write $a\star b$ with $a$, $b$ and $\ell$ the number of $b$?

Your statement needs some restrictions on the value of $n$. For example, if $n=99$, the LHS gives $9801$ when the RHS is $981$.

What is the mathematical definition of the "concatenation of integers"?

If this is a statement, what is the question? Are you asking if this claim is true?

Your claim isn't true in general!
For example, take $n=99$. Then the left hand side of the equation gives $9801$ and the right hand side is $981$.

To see why it seems true, and what restriction on $n$ we can add to make it true, let's try to prove it.
First, notice that $a\star b=a\cdot 10^\ell +b$ where $\ell$ is the number of digits of $b$. Therefore, the left hand side can be rewritten as
$$n\star n -2n=n\cdot 10^{\ell}+n-2n=n\cdot 10^\ell -n=n\cdot (10^\ell -1)$$
where $\ell$ is the number of digits of $n$. The right hand side can also be simplified:
$$(n-1)\star\frac{n\star n -n -n^2}{n}=(n-1)\star\frac{n\cdot 10^\ell +n-n-n^2}{n}=(n-1)\star (10^\ell-n)$$
Now, if $n$ and $10^\ell-n$ share the same number of digits ($\dagger$), then it reduces to
$$(n-1)\star (10^\ell -n)=(n-1)\cdot 10^\ell +(10^\ell -n)=n\cdot 10^\ell -n=n\cdot (10^\ell -1)$$
So, under condition ($\dagger$), your claim is true! In fact, your claim is equivalent to $n$ and $10^\ell$ sharing the same number of digits: indeed, if $10^\ell-n$ has $p$ digits, then the right hand side is
$$(n-1)\star (10^\ell -n)=10^p\cdot (n-1)+(10^\ell -n)$$
so equality holds if and only if
$$(10^p-10^\ell)\cdot n=0$$
which (if we exclude the case $n=0$), is clearly equivalent to $\ell=p$.
Condition ($\dagger$) happens if and only if
$$n\in\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N_0}[\![10^k,9\cdot 10^k]\!]=\mathbb N\setminus \{91,\dots,99,901,\dots,999,9001,\dots\}.$$
i.e. either the leading digit of $n$ is not $9$, or $n=9\cdot 10^k$ for some integer $k$.
Example: $n=23$ has the same number of digits as $77=100-23$, so your claim works for this choice of $n$.
Remark: the set of integers $n$ for which your claim holds has natural density $8/9$.

For such a number $n$, and equivalent statement would be to say that
$$\frac{n^2}{n\star n}=0.\overline{(n-1)\star (10^\ell-n)}\quad\quad (\ddagger)$$
(see repeating decimal notation). Indeed, the above statement is equivalent to
$$\frac{n^2}{n\star n}(10^{2\ell}-1)=(n-1)\star (10^\ell -n)$$
(because $2\ell$ would be the length of the period). Using the fact that $10^{2\ell}-1=(10^\ell -1)(10^\ell +1)$ and $n\star n=n(10^\ell +1)$, one obtains
$$\frac{n^2}{n\star n}(10^{2\ell}-1)=n(10^\ell -1)=n(10^\ell+1)-2n=n\star n -2n$$
which is equal to $(n-1)\star (10^\ell -n)$ when your claim holds, and leads to ($\ddagger$).
Example: for $n=23$,
$$\frac{n^2}{n\star n}=\frac{529}{2323}=0.\overline{2277}\text{ and }(n-1)\star (10^\ell -n)=22\star 77=2277$$

Some generalizations: (that could be fun working on!)

define $n^{\star p}:=n\star \dots\star n$, so that
$$n^{\star p}=n\frac{10^{p\ell}-1}{10^\ell -1}$$
where $\ell$ is the number of digits of $n$ (in base 10). The famous repunits sequence (see OEIS entry A002275) would be written $(1^{\star n})_n$. One can easily show that the decimal period of $n^p/n^{\star p}$ is divisible by $n\star n -2n$.
Example: for $(n,p)=(23,3)$,
$$\frac{23^3}{232323}=0.\overline{052371}\text{ and }52371=23\times 2277=n\times \left[n\star n -2n\right] $$
what about other bases? In base $b$,
$$n\star n=n(b^\ell+1)\text{ and more generally }n^{\star p}=n\frac{b^{p\ell}-1}{b^\ell -1}$$
where $\ell =\lceil \log_b(n)\rceil$ is the number of digits of $n$ in base $b$.
[...]

I'd love to hear any other ideas/developments.

Kolakoski54. And can you show that n^2/n⋆n =0.(n−1)⋆(10^ℓ−n) in the period. Example 23^2/2323 = 0.(23-1)⋆(10^2−23) = 0.(2277)

I edited my answer, feel free to accept it if you think it is complete enough!

Kolakoski54.
I really liked your answer. Is there any way I can contact you so that I can leave you a couple of my other mathematical findings. Here is my telegram channel
https://web.telegram.org/a/#-1002257827796

I have enough math to do for myself, sorry. If you can phrase your problem well enough, providing details, examples, some things you tried,... then I'm sure it will be well received on MSE, and everyone could try to help you figure out the last details of your proofs! If you really liked my answer, I am sure you can accept it, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer for more details.

That's it, I accepted the answer

Kolakoski54. Yes, I have other studies on this topic, I can send you a link to my researchgate page. But here is the most elegant formula that I have derived
n⋆k:=n⋆⋯⋆n =((n⋆n - n)^k - n^k)/((n⋆n - 2*n)·n^(k-2)). https://www.researchgate.net/publication/385130264_Issledovanie_formuly_konkatenacii_cisel_vida_nnnnnnn
